# Is there a report or notification for user stories moved out of an iteration?

Tags: notifications, azure-devops

**Situation:** I'm using Azure DevOps and doing release management for several products. Each product has multiple product owners, PMs and team members who update ADO regularly. On occasion a story is moved to a different iteration. I don't know when this happens unless I'm told by the person doing it or notice it when reviewing story queries.

**Goal:** I'd like to track any stories that get moved to a different iteration (or the backlog) after the sprint has begun. Basically, if it gets moved, I want to know about it.

I've tinkered with the Notifications feature, but haven't figured out how to get this info.

**Ask:** Is there a report, dashboard widget or notification setting I can use for this? If not, is there a way I could do it with a query? Ideally, I'd like a report/widget so I can track carryover, sprint to sprint. But I'll take whatever I can get. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a complete resolution for this question with no manual workaround.

- Asking for when either the Area Path or Iteration changes (at all) will yield any/all changes to paths. However, every new item created is technically a change, so it gets those as well.
- By using "Rev > 1" it filters out the new items. (New work items are created with a Rev of 1 and subsequent modifications will increment that number.)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind doing a little maintenance sprint to sprint, you can probably use a notification to see when things are change.  Once you've finalized the current sprint scope, just update the notification to the current sprint's value.

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're suggesting. None of the work items are assigned to me -- the team leads/scrum masters assign the work items to the various engineers.

Answer (score 0):

> None of the work items are assigned to me -- the team leads/scrum
>   masters assign the work items to the various engineers

For this issue, you just need to select "**Deliver to**" field in subscription as **Team preference** or **Members of XX Team**. So even if no work items are assigned to you, as long as you are a member of the team, you will receive an email notification when the iteration path of work items changes.
[image]

Receive notification as shown below:
[image]

So the work around that Matt gives is good.This can satisfy your demand.Hope my supplement could help you.

Comment: Yours absolutely did -- and Matt's answer was what I needed. I wish I could use "@CurrentIteration" instead of a specific iteration, but alas -- I'll deal with it. :)